# thymeleaf and condition and list size

Tags: thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf 3 and I try to use an "and" in a condition and use the size of a list in the condition

```
<div th:if="${param.isGenerated and #lists.size(param.options) lt 1}" th:remove="tag">
    <label th:text="${param.value}"></label>
</div>
```

I get this error

> org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL
>   expression:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
${param.isGenerated and #lists.isEmpty(param.options)}
```